# Resigned Windows app showing warning when downloaded

Tags: windows, windows-10, code-signing

We have an Windows desktop application signed using a GoDaddy certificate. The certificate expired recently so, for the latest upgrade of the software, we went through the steps of renewing the certificate and signing the new version.

When we try to install the software on a fresh machine, we see a dialog from SmartScreen stating that an unauthorized has been prevented from running. We haven't experienced this behavior with the previous versions of our software using the old certificate.

When we compare the previous version (signed before the certificate expired) and the new version by going to Properties > Digital Signatures > Details, we notice that most of the properties are the same (including things like the Public Key, Authority Key Identifier, Subject Key Identifier, etc). The Serial Key and Thumbprint are different, and obviously the dates.

Additionally the Certificate Policies are different. The old msi had this value:

```
[1]Certificate Policy:
     Policy Identifier=2.16.840.1.114413.1.7.23.2
     [1,1]Policy Qualifier Info:
          Policy Qualifier Id=CPS
          Qualifier:
               http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/
```

while the new msi has:

```
[1]Certificate Policy:
     Policy Identifier=2.16.840.1.114413.1.7.23.2
     [1,1]Policy Qualifier Info:
          Policy Qualifier Id=CPS
          Qualifier:
               http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/
[2]Certificate Policy:
     Policy Identifier=2.23.140.1.4.1
```

I'm not sure how relevant the above information is, I was hoping if anyone could shed any light as to what's going on and how we can resolve this issue?

Comment: The additional policy is unlikely to impact SmartScreen. The policy IDs are created by Starfield (GoDaddys CA) - see here - https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/previous_versions/StarfieldCertificatePolicyandCertificationPracticeStatement_V310.pdf - and I doub't microsoft knows how to interpret them.